# Not able to setup Splash for R using Docker

Tags: r, docker

Error in highlighted command
[image: Error in highlighted command]

I installed docker toolbox to use splashr package in R and followed steps to install splash. But,  I am getting an error saying "**C:\Program Files\Docker Toolbox\docker.exe: Error response from daemon: driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint**"

Error which I am getting in R is --

"**render_png(url = "https://analytics.usa.gov/", wait = 5)
Error in curl::curl_fetch_memory(url, handle = handle) : 
  Failed to connect to localhost port 8050: Connection refused**"

Can anybody help me out on this please?

Comment: `splashr` author here. I don't have a non-VM version of Windows so testing this is somewhat impossible for me. This sounds like there may be another process listening on port 8050 (e.g. https://github.com/jwilder/nginx-proxy/issues/839) can you try using `8051:8050 5024:5023` (increment the #'s until they work, perhaps). To test outside of R you can use your browser to try to hit http://localhost:8050 (use the port that works). This is definitely a Docker+Windows issue, though.